# anychart(v7) linked label to another site (using js)

Tags: javascript, apex, anychart

chart: [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GVtbJ.png) 
hi, i work with oracle apex and anychart. My question is, it is possible to adress this `<g>` and its "value" 'N0003'? I would like to link to another page, for example by clicking  'N0003'. The label 'N0003' can not be set as a link. ('N0003'.link("alink") does not work in anychart)

```
<g data-ac-wrapper-id="396" clip-path="url(##ac_clip_7)" clipPathUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
    <text data-ac-wrapper-id="397" unselectable="on" onselectstart="return false;" font-style="normal" font-variant="normal" font-family="Verdana, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif" font-size="7" font-weight="normal" fill="#212121" letter-spacing="normal" text-decoration="none" direction="ltr" text-anchor="middle" x="68.5" y="42" aria-hidden="true" style="user-select: none; opacity: 1;">
        <tspan onselectstart="return false;" unselectable="on" dy="0">N0003</tspan>
    </text>
</g>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a link field to one or several points this way: `{x: "2010", y: "A", heat: 15, link: "https://www.anychart.com/"}`. Then you can set a listener on pointClick event, and open a link from the 'link' field if it exists:

```
chart.listen('pointClick', function (e) {
    if (e.point.get('link') != undefined) {
      window.open(e.point.get('link'));
    }
  });
```

Check this [sample](https://playground.anychart.com/mMVUyIl9).